# Getting error messages while creating new Community

Tags: community, developer-edition

After going to - Setup -> Customize > Communities > Manage Communities

I have given only name field value as ghelp, which is required field.

- Name - ghelp
  Description - 
  URL gopaldas-developer-edition.ap1.force.com /

I am getting below message -

An error occurred while creating Site samples
Error creating SiteRegisterController sample controller: (30,9): Variable does not exist: Username

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error before and it seemed to be a Bug then. It looks like the issue is related to SiteRegisterController, so create the empty SiteRegisterControllerTest class and that will solve the problem

---

There is a known issue regarding this which was fixed earlier but try the above workaround.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyduAAC

Summary
Unable to create communities in certain orgs that have external ID or unique fields, validation rules, or triggers on the user object. The error appears "Oops, something went wrong; please refresh the page and try again" after trying to create a community.

Repro
1. Login as the admin of the org 
2. Go to the Manage Communities Page 
3. Click the New Community Button 
4. Enter the name, description and URL 
5. Click the Create button and the following appears "Oops, something went wrong; please refresh the page and try again."

Workaround
Remove any external ID or unique fields, validation rules, or triggers on the user object. Otherwise create the empty class definitions (that is, the class is defined, but no methods or properties within them are needed) in the problematic orgs:

ChangePasswordControllerTest 
ForgotPasswordControllerTest 
MyProfilePageControllerTest 
SiteLoginControllerTest 
SiteRegisterControllerTest

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another user besides yourself as the admin. It sounds as though the message is telling you that you have no users with which to create a community for. The other user should be a standard user or the type of user you're creating the community for, not another admin.